# How to make a number variable change when a button is pressed? Actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I need the number variable to change each time a button is pressed. The variable is called "total".

**my stage code:**

```
var total:Number = 4;

if (total == 5){
    gotoAndPlay (2) 
}

else if (total == 6){ 
    gotoAndPlay (5)  
}

else {
    trace("there was an error ya PUTZ!!!") 
}
```

**my Button code:**

```
on (release) {
    set(total, 5);
}
```

Nothing happens when the button is pressed.
There is nothing in the Compiler Errors.

Sorry if this is a stupid question. Im ass new to code and it can sometimes be hard to find flash tutorials.
even sorry-er if this is formatted weird, still learning how to use this site and all that sorta stuff....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are starting anew, I advise to start with **AS3**, not **AS1/2**. **Flash** is dead anyway, but **AS2** is like 15 years since obsolete so the amount and quality of tutorials and references are next to non-existent.

Then, your problem.

I don't remember, if **set** command is what I think you expect it to, but the basic **=** operator is still more readable and easier to understand.

Then, as you press the button, nothing seem to happen because your frame code is not a sleeping watchdog. It executes once and that's it. In order to get some reaction, you should set up some kind of watcher.

Frame script:

```
var store:Number = 4;
var total:Number = 4;

// This is a predefined method name that will fire FPS times a second,
// where FPS stands for Frames Per Second setting of your application.
function onEnterFrame()
{
    // Check if the variable is actually changed.
    if (total == store)
    {
        // Refrain from action if not.
        return;
    }
    
    if (total == 5)
    {
        // Keep the new value.
        store = total;
        
        // The desired action.
        gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
    else if (total == 6)
    {
        // Keep the new value.
        store = total;
        
        // The desired action.
        gotoAndPlay(5);
    }
    else
    {
        // Revert the variable.
        total = store;
        
        // Notify the user.
        trace("there was an error ya PUTZ!!!");
    }
}
```

The button code:

```
on (release)
{
    total = 5;
}
```